# Matlab converte UNIX time to Human readable format

Tags: matlab, datetime, csv, unix-timestamp

I got one problem with UNIX time to human readable time. In fact I was also thinking is it possible to conterte UNIX time to Comma-separated-values...so that I can make a plot based on this converted real time and the corresponding values.

But my UNIX is in int64 format, I tried using

```
unix_epoch = datenum(1970,1,1,0,0,0);
for i=1:1:size(data_mat)
matlab_time(i,1) = data_mat(i,1)./86400 + unix_epoch; 
end
```

for example: 1352434077. So when I tried to converte it with this code: It gave 735087..not something like YYYY-MM-DD: hh:mm:ss ...can anyone gave me a hint? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`datestr`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html) (the output of which is a string):

```
>> time_num = 735087
time_num =  735087
>> datestr(time_num)
ans = 06-Aug-2012
```

You can also specify a format for the output, such as `'dd-mmm-yyyy HH:MM:SS'`, check the doc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply am304...In fact I tried this many times...with numbers only, it works. But my time series is in UNIX format...and stored in 13892760 X 2 int64...so when I tried usng this function. it always gives:                     `Error using dateformverify (line 28)
DATESTR failed converting date number to date vector.

Error in datestr (line 195)
S = dateformverify(dtnumber, dateformstr, islocal);

Caused by:
    Error using datevecmx
    The datevecmx function only accepts double arrays.`

Comment: It sounds like you need to convert your number to double. Use the double function for this.

Comment: I converted it to double...it gives this error again:       `Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts`

Comment: It sounds to me as if the problem is with how your data is formatted and stored. Without having access to the data to reproduce the issue and knowing how it is formatted, there's not much we can do...

Comment: Hello am304,    Thanks, you are right...it is difficult to say ...My data is in workspace Value: 13892770 X 2 int64 ...i do not knwo if it is possible I can send it to you...it takes me some days already this problem...

Comment: Can you upload your data on a filesharing site and post the link here? I don't understand what "13892760 X 2 int64" means...

Comment: Thanks am304. I found out my value is UNIX time in int64 format. So I managed with this following code:
`
`x=datestr([1]*double(Data(1:10,1)./86400+datenum(1970,1,1,0,0,0)),'yyyymmddTHH:MM:SS');`

The result is

`20121109T00:00:00
20121109T00:00:00
20121109T00:00:00
20121109T00:00:00
20121109T00:00:00

20121109T00:00:00
20121109T00:00:00
20121109T00:00:00
20121109T00:00:00
20121109T00:00:00`
`
Why the hour, minute and second are all 0? can you see any errors here I made? Thanks

Comment: A few questions: what does the `[1]` do? Why have you got a `T` in the date format? I am not sure this is a valid date string format. Finally, what does `datestr(double(Data(1:10,1)./86400))` return?